# Percentage axis in bar plot Julia

Tags: julia, bar-chart, axis, percentage, statsplots.jl

I am using [this](https://goropikari.github.io/PlotsGallery.jl/src/stacked_bar_plot.html) stacked bar plot example to create a stacked bar plot with a percentage axis. Here is some reproducible code:

```
using StatsPlots

measles = [38556, 24472, 14556, 18060, 19549, 8122, 28541, 7880, 3283, 4135, 7953, 1884]
mumps = [20178, 23536, 34561, 37395, 36072, 32237, 18597, 9408, 6005, 6268, 8963, 13882]
chickenPox = [37140, 32169, 37533, 39103, 33244, 23269, 16737, 5411, 3435, 6052, 12825, 23332]

ticklabel = string.(collect('A':'L'))
groupedbar([measles mumps chickenPox],
        bar_position = :stack,
        bar_width=0.7,
        xticks=(1:12, ticklabel),
        label=["measles" "mumps" "chickenPox"])
```

Output:

[image]

So now it is a nice stacked values barplot, but I would like to make the y-axis in percentage with range from 0 to 100%. Unfortunately there is no option like `scale = :percent`. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to make this barplot with percentage y-axis in `Julia`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabe this can give you a idea:

```
foo = @. measles + mumps + chickenPox
my_range = LinRange(0, maximum(foo), 11)

groupedbar(
  [measles mumps chickenPox],
  bar_position = :stack,
  bar_width=0.7,
  xticks=(1:12, ticklabel),
  yticks=(my_range, 0:0.1:1),
  label=["measles" "mumps" "chickenPox"]
)
```

[image]

Explanation:
The idea is to map a linear range from zero up to the height of the tallest bar in the plot. So, first I should find the tallest bar in the plot; for this, I should achieve to values of the height of each bar:

```
julia> foo = @. measles + mumps + chickenPox
12-element Vector{Int64}:
 95874
 80177
 86650
 94558
 88865
 63628
 63875
 22699
 12723
 16455
 29741
 39098
```

Then, I use the maximum of `foo` to create my linear range from zero to the maximum value:

```
julia> my_range = LinRange(0, maximum(foo), 11)
11-element LinRange{Float64, Int64}:
 0.0,9587.4,19174.8,28762.2,38349.6,47937.0,57524.4,67111.8,76699.2,86286.6,95874.0
```

Now I use this range in the `groupedbar` function for its keyword argument, named `yticks` to scale the range `0:0.1:1` to the extremum value of the plot. If you want to change the range from zero to 100 (instead of percent interpretation), then just replace `0:0.1:1` with `0:10:100` in the `yticks`.